# My Qt program showing blank window with title

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-creator

I am new to Qt and I have this code that is supposed to display a slider bar and number box in Qt main window. But all I am getting is the main window itself and nothing in it. I did use show() function but nothing happend

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QSpinBox>
#include <QSlider>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QtGui/QApplicationStateChangeEvent>



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow program ;

    program.setWindowTitle("Title of window");


    QSpinBox *spinboxx = new QSpinBox();
    QSlider *slider = new QSlider(Qt::Horizontal);
    spinboxx->setRange(1,40);
    slider->setRange(1,40);

QObject::connect(spinboxx, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), slider, SLOT(setValue(int)));
QObject::connect(slider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), spinboxx, SLOT(setValue(int)));
QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout;

layout->addWidget(slider);
layout->addWidget(spinboxx);
program.setLayout(layout);
    program.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Side note: do not use `<QtModule/QClass>` includes. All `Qt` includes should be single-element, either `<QClass>` or `<QtModule>`. The module/class format hides project misconfigurations and merely pushes compile errors to link time, where the problem has been in the `.pro` file all along (or a stale build folder).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an important warning when compiling your code:

> QWidget::setLayout: Attempting to set QLayout "" on QMainWindow "",
>   which already has a layout

In fact, you cannot set a layout for `QMainWindow`, since it has its own layout. From the [Documentation of Qt5](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html):

> A main window provides a framework for building an application's user
>   interface. Qt has QMainWindow and its related classes for main window
>   management. **QMainWindow has its own layout** to which you can add
>   QToolBars, QDockWidgets, a QMenuBar, and a QStatusBar. The layout has
>   a center area that can be occupied by any kind of widget.

You should assign a widget to the `QMainWindow` *program* instead like so:

```
QWidget *window = new QWidget;
QSpinBox *spinboxx = new QSpinBox();
QSlider *slider = new QSlider(Qt::Horizontal);

QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout;
layout->addWidget(slider);
layout->addWidget(spinboxx);

window->setLayout(layout);


QMainWindow program ;
program.setWindowTitle("Title of window");
program.setCentralWidget(window);
program.show();
```

PS: I kept the name convention you chose to make the changes clearer. I would rather use *widget* than *window* and *window* than *program*

Comment: Makes so much sense! Thanks a lot!